# aligning columns in table layout Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I would like to align my table layout contents (textviews) with at least 3 columns straight with each other like this(i hope you can see it)

item1a     item1b     item1c
item2a     item2b     item2c

and so on, and im populating these values from the database through a custom listview. this is what i have done so far, may you help me

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp">





<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
   android:stretchColumns="*"     android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


<!-- Row 1 with single column -->
<TableRow
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:id="@+id/textsdid"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:id="@+id/textsdrtype"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:id="@+id/textstaxperiod"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="#000"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:id="@+id/textsdduedate"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:textAlignment="center" />




      </TableRow>


      </TableLayout>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with above code?? Make it clear